# Are elements distinguished in the category of sets?

Tags: category-theory

In the wiki page of [**pointed set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_set), they refer to the zero object as:

> the pointed singleton set $(\{a\},a)$

It seems that $(\{a\},a)$ and $(\{b\},b)$ when $a \ne b$ are not distinguished. Is it the same case in the [category of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_sets) (**Set**)? That is, is there only one object representing singletons in **Set**, only one object representing two-element sets, and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, every set is a distinct object in the category **Set**.

However, all category-theoretical properties of objects are preserved by isomorphisms. In particular, if some object is a zero object, then any object isomorphic to is also is a zero object. We say that there is a unique zero object, *up to isomorphism*.

For sets, an isomorphism is just a bijection; any two sets with equal cardinality are isomorphic. So, while there are a lot of one-element sets, they share the same properties from category-theoretic viewpoint, like do all two-element sets, and so on.